# Send notification to all users in laravel with all users data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, notifications, laravel-8

I want to send notification to all users and want to pass all users data to MyNotification class

```
Notification::send($users, new MyNotification($users));
```

In that way MyNotification class constructor will receive the collection of all users and it returns the error

> Property [first_name] does not exist on this collection instance

MyNotificatioin.php

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('Dear ' . $this->users->first_name . ',')
        ->line('Your profile has been updated.')
        ->action('View Profile', url('/'));
}
```

So my question is, how I can pass all users data to MyNotification class or I will need to run foreach loop in MyNotification class to get every user's first_name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your toMail function you would use the $notifiable variable (which is the user) instead of trying to use the users collection.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->line('Dear ' . $notifiable->first_name . ',')
        ->line('Your profile has been updated.')
        ->action('View Profile', url('/'));
}
```

I'm also not sure why you are passing all users in to the MyNotification, this is not required.